Swiftinterface file only has reference to a single class
Im building an XCFramework for distribution.  All of the classes and properties i want exposed and accessible are marked open or public.  I have several classes and files in this framework, but when i open and view the .swiftinterface file i only see reference to a single class, and thus when i import this framework in my project the non referenced properties are unavailable.
The generated .swiftinterface looks like
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
// swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 6.0.2 effective-5.10 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)
// swift-module-flags: -target arm64-apple-ios14.5-simulator -enable-objc-interop -enable-library-evolution -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -enable-bare-slash-regex -module-name MyFramework
// swift-module-flags-ignorable: -no-verify-emitted-module-interface
import Foundation
@_exported import MyFramework
import Swift
import _Concurrency
import _StringProcessing
import _SwiftConcurrencyShims
open class MyFrameworkClass : Swift.Decodable {
  open var url: Swift.String?
  open var parameters: MyFrameworkProperty.Parameters?
  public init(url: Swift.String? = nil, parameters: MyFrameworkProperty.Parameters? = nil)
  @objc deinit
  required public init(from decoder: any Swift.Decoder) throws
}
open class Parameters : Swift.Decodable {
  open var PropertyA: Swift.String?
  open var PropertyB: Swift.String?
  open var PropertyC: Swift.String?
  public init(PropertyA: Swift.String? = nil, PropertyB: Swift.String? = nil, PropertyC: Swift.String? = nil)
  @objc deinit
  required public init(from decoder: any Swift.Decoder) throws
}
public enum PropertyC : Swift.String, Swift.CaseIterable {
  case a
  case b
  case c
  public init?(rawValue: Swift.String)
  public typealias AllCases = [MyFramework.PropertyC]
  public typealias RawValue = Swift.String
  nonisolated public static var allCases: [MyFramework.PropertyC] {
    get
  }
  public var rawValue: Swift.String {
    get
  }
}
extension MyFramework.PropertyC : Swift.Equatable {}
extension MyFramework.PropertyC : Swift.Hashable {}
extension MyFramework.PropertyC : Swift.RawRepresentable {}


i compiled these using the following commands
xcodebuild archive -workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace \
-scheme MyFramework \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
-archivePath './build/MyFramework.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive -workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace \
-scheme MyFramework \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath './build/MyFramework.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \                          
-framework './build/MyFramework.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework' \
-framework './build/MyFramework.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework' \
-output './build/MyFramework.xcframework'


MyFramework.h file from my framework before compilation looks like
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];

What is required to have all my public/open properties available to the project that imports the xcframework?

What does your framework's header file look like?

are you referring to the MyFramework.h file from precompilation or the MyFramework-Swift.h file in the XCFramework?  If the latter, i do not see any of the classes or methods from my framework in it.  When i analyzed the -Swift.h file on a different, working framework of mine i do see reference to my classes in there.
FWIW if i import this library via a cocoapods private repo it compiles fine.  It seems to be this point of compiling to xcframework where im running into problems

Yes, it's a tricky process. But you haven't told us anything at all about how you're doing it.

Ive updated the original post with contents of my .h file and how im creating the xcframework.  Im sorry for the ignorance, im a little green with doing this in a closed source variety, i appreciate any help you provide.

The answer turned out to be rather obvious - i had many files with no target member.  The only one that had target ownership was the one that i could see its classes in the .swiftinterface file.  Adding the files to my frameworks target resolved the problems.
